# Where is the Spring Framework 2.x source code repository?

Tags: spring, repository

Looks like it was EOL-ed years ago, but I still would like to find some "official" repository for Spring 2.x (managed by Spring) where I can download the repo and build it locally. The Spring GitHub repo only has versions after Spring 3.x.

Comment: Not sure if the old svn is still accessible, but you should be able to find a distribution of Spring which includes the sources. Those came as a zip back in the days :).

Comment: Thanks M, I'm looking for a repo that has some semblance of being "official", do you think anything like this still exists? (perhaps curated by Spring?)  So far no luck :/

Comment: There is no official repo besides the githb one. As stated you are best of with the zips. Why do you need the sources anyway? You could try `https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-framework/` and hope that there is more in earlier revisions...

Comment: I am attempting to patch a security vulnerability in an older version, and therefore would need to download the source, patch the vulnerability, and then build the artifact again from source, but if the source code repo isn't trusted, then there are no assurances that this source code doesn't contain malicious code or even works correctly.  Thanks, I think you are right.

Comment: The official zips contain the original sources.